# ComboBox in X++

Tags: combobox, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

In my `ComboBox` there are items like  `A B C D` and bydefault the value is `A` where i want to make it as `C` something like `comboBox.comboType(2)`  in the init form, but this doesnt seems to work.
May be `ComboBox.selection(2)` helps, m not sure, Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in the form's `init` method after `super()`:

```
ComboBoxName.selection(ComboBoxName::DefaultValue);
```

If this is a table field I'd suggest overriding the `initValue` method in the table:

```
this.ComboBoxName = ComboBoxName::DefaultValue;
```

Override `initValue` in the form's datasource only if it should be a specific behaviour in this form only.

Comment: thanks, i got confused whether to write the code in `init` or `initValue` but your answer clarified my doubts...thnks once again.

Comment: could you plz explain the reason of using the code after `super()`?

Comment: And also `this.ComboBoxName = ComboBoxName::DefaultValue;` is not working instead i have to put the datasource name then only it works why?

Comment: 1) If you try using it before `super()` you'll get a "FormComboBoxControl object not initialized" error message. 2) "this.ComboBoxName" should be used in "\Data Dictionary\Tables\TableName\Methods\initValue"

Answer (score 0):

All I did is overrided the initValue method of the form n wrote the code as `tableName.ComboBoxName = ComboBoxName::DefaultValue;`

And its working fine. Correct me if I am wrong :)